# Directory/Namespace Structure for versioned REST API

Tags: php, api, rest, domain-driven-design, versioning

I have read a lot of best practices for versioning the URI of an RESTful API e.g (`http://api.example.com/v1/users` -> `http://api.example.com/v2/users` and also [HATEOAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HATEOAS)), but not much about the directory or namespace structure in my code base (PHP+silex framework).
What my code base can do right now: The code base itself supports multiple versions of the API, recognize version by route or Accept header and can call different controllers/classes/methods based on identified API version (e.g. in v1 `UserController::listUsers()`, in v2: `UserControllerV2::getListUsers()`).
The API will have more and more versions over the time, but at some point old versions should be removed from code base.

So the questions are

- What classes should be versioned? (controllers,models,views, etc...)
- How to did it when you have bundles domain driven design involved? (version the complete bundles directory or just inside a bundle?)
- How should they versioned?  (Class inheritence (How?), Directory structure...)

  - With less code duplication,
  - easy removal of old version
  - less side effects if you bug fix something that is shared between versions

Current `src` directory structure is e.g. (`public`, `vendor` is one level up):

```
   .
   └── TestNext
       ├── ApiV1
       │   └── Route
       │       └── ApiV1RoutesProvider.php
       ├── Configuration
       │   ├── Controller
       │   ├── Loader
       │   │   └── YamlConfigLoader.php
       │   ├── Model
       │   └── Service
       │       └── SymfonyConfigServiceProvider.php
       ├── Security
       │   └── Authenticator
       │       └── TokenAuthenticator.php
       ├── Shared
       │   └── Controller
       │       └── BaseController.php
       ├── User
       │   ├── Controller
       │   │   └── UserController.php
       │   ├── Model
       │   └── Service
       ├── Bootstrap.php
       ├── Console.php
       └── Constants.php
```

Answer (score 3):

First off, it's worth separating concepts apart. You have your domain, and you have an API tier. Following layering, your API tier should sit above (and "separate") to your domain, and your domain should be completely unaware of the existence of an API. It helps to structure things around this, one way to do it is like follows:

```
src/Acme/Api/
src/Acme/Core/
```

Everything in API handles HTTP level communications; routing, request & response mapping, status codes, etc.

Everything in Core handles business related actions. Following a CQRS style approach, you could end with something like:

```
src/Acme/Api/Controller
src/Acme/Api/DTO/Request/
src/Acme/Api/DTO/Response/
src/Core/Domain/
src/Core/Command/
src/Core/CommandHandler/
src/Core/Infrastructure/
src/Core/ReadModel/
```

But really, the layout & naming is going to be flexible, and it somewhat depends what architectural patterns you're applying. In the DDD context, the key point is you place your aggregates, models, value objects & repositories together under some common namespace (`Domain`).

To address your individual questions:

> What classes should be versioned? (controllers,models,views, etc...)

In my mind it does not make sense to version models. Models should always be an up to date representation of the business, and maintaining *older* rules would seem unnecessary.

How you handle a versioning is up to you. You can either treat it as a way to version the API it's entirety (paths + request/response payloads), or just request/response payloads. Versioning the API in it's entirely is probably the most flexible, but making such dramatic changes is relatively rare. You might want to consider leveraging the `Accept` / `Content-Type` headers to version on a per request level. You can even use a combination of both (major version bump in the URL to redefine paths and force particular `Content-Type`s versions).

Theoretically you could go even further, and version your JSON schema, which define your request/response payloads. As an example:

````
GET /1.0/user/317684e2-3704-11e6-8172-b0bea8105888/payment/2caad76e-3705-11e6-8172-b0bea8105888
Accept: application/vnd+acme+json; schema=payment.out.v1.json

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/vnd+acme+json; schema=payment.out.v1.json;     charset=UTF-8

{
  "payee": "Bob Dylan",
  // snip
}
```
````

If you want to introduce a non-backwards compatible change to the response payload, then you can allow clients to request against the "v2" JSON schema for payments:

```
GET /1.0/user/317684e2-3704-11e6-8172-b0bea8105888/payment/2caad76e-3705-11e6-8172-b0bea8105888
Accept: application/vnd+acme+json; schema=payment.out.v2.json

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Type: application/vnd+acme+json; schema=payment.out.v2.json; charset=UTF-8

{
  "payee": {
    "forename": "Bob",
    "surname": "Dylan"
  },
  // snip
}
```

The major API version in unchanged, but the response payloads differ. In time you could deprecate older versions, or indeed bump the major API version and set a minimum at the payload levels.

The same technique can be applied for request bodies by leveraging the `Content-Type` header.

> How to did it when you have bundles domain driven design involved? (version the complete bundles directory or just inside a bundle?)
>   How should they versioned? (Class inheritence (How?), Directory structure...)

Perhaps it's already answered, but try not to think in terms of Symfony style bundles. Your `Core`, or whatever you want to call it, should have nothing Symfony/Silex specific in it. In `Infrastructure` you might have implementations of `Repository` interfaces, perhaps using Doctrine, but that's us leveraging Doctrine as a library, rather than leaning on Symfony/Silex as a framework. If you do it well, in theory you could swap out the API layer for an entirely different framework without any changes to `Core`.

There are a couple of unavoidable things though: dependency injection & configuration. With Symfony, I've created a `CoreBundle` to solve this in the past. This sits outside of `Core`.

By the way, it's probably wise to only encompass one bounded context within such a project, so don't worry about categorising things much further.

> With less code duplication,

It's inevitable that duplication occurs, but when this should only be the case for your DTOs, as you won't be versioning objects that define behaviour (your models). Duplication in DTOs isn't a big deal really. If more clarity is gained than lost, then simply define a class per version. Tools might tell you code has been copy pasted, but these aren't tools capable of understanding such context.

> easy removal of old version

If you define separate DTOs, then such a task should be simple. Drop the DTOs, drop the JSON schema, and now your API should reject requests with the older versions specified.

> less side effects if you bug fix something that is shared between versions

If you are mapping to request/response objects in your API tier, then it's your mapping code that can be affected by changes in models. Good test coverage (via API contract tests, in-process component tests, and unit tests) should verify that changes to your models do not result in all versions of your API behaving differently.